# If $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos x-e^x\cos x+e^x-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$ is a non zero finite number number, find $n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> If the following limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos x-e^x\cos x+e^x-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$
>   is a non zero finite number number, find $n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos^2x-\cos x-e^x\cos x+e^x-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\cos x-e^x)(\cos x-1)-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(\cos x-e^x)\frac{(\cos x-1)}{x^2}-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$

Since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\cos x-1)}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$
$$\implies \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2(\cos x-e^x)\frac{(\cos x-1)}{x^2}-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}(\cos x-e^x)-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$
Since $\cos x$ is $1$ when $x$ tends to zero,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}(\cos x-e^x)-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}(1-e^x)-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$
Since $\frac{1-e^x}{x}$ tends to $-1$ when $x\to 0$, 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac{x^2}{2}(1-e^x)-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}x-\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n}$$
Isnt the answer $n=3$? Answer given is $n=4$

Comment: Can you use Taylor series ? It should be quite fast.

Comment: I think you can't just take limits in one part of the numerator and leave the other parts untouched. As Claude suggested, using Taylor series is probably the best way to do this.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: As usual, you paved the way of solving it markedly! :-)

Comment: @S.Snape. I cannot resist ! 60 years in love with Taylor series !! Cheers.

Comment: I give you "my" trick : when I see a polynomial term of degree $p$ in numerator, it is almost sure that you will need to develop up to degree $p+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor series of $\cos^2 x - \cos x - e^x \cos x + e^x$ is
$$\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2}+O(x^5)$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^2 x - \cos x - e^x \cos x + e^x - \frac{x^3}{2}}{x^n} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^4}{2} + O(x^5)}{x^n}$$

If $n = 3$, the limit goes to 0, but it is given that the limit is non-zero finite. Therefore $n = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace $(1-\cos x)/x^2$ with $1/2$. This can only be done for a “global factor”, not for a summand in a longer expression.

Consider, for instance,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^n}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\left(1-\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)}{x^n}
$$
where you can't replace $\sin x/x$ with $1$.

---

Apply l’Hôpital as many times as needed, under the assumption you continue to get an indeterminate form; consider
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\cos^2x-\cos x-e^x\cos x+e^x-\frac{x^3}{2} && f(0)=0 \\
f'(x)&=-2\sin x\cos x+\sin x-e^x\cos x+e^x\sin x+e^x-\frac{3x^2}{2} && f'(0)=0 \\[4px]
f''(x)&=-2\cos2x+\cos x+2e^x\sin x+e^x-3x && f''(0)=0 \\[8px]
f'''(x)&=4\sin2x-\sin x+2e^x\sin x+2e^x\cos x+e^x-3 && f'''(0)=0 \\[8px]
f''''(x)&=8\cos2x-\cos x+4e^x\cos x+e^x && f''''(0)=12
\end{align}
So, for $0\le n<4$, the limit is $0$; if $n=4$, the limit is $1/2$.

You can also compute the Taylor expansion, but I'm not sure that in this case it's shorter.